# Linq-to-SQL partial loading of association

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, deferred-loading

I have XCore and XEvent associated tables (XCore.Id => XEvent.CoreId). XCore table has few rows and XEvent has more than 163000 of rows. Inside of XCore methods I want to write (for example):

```
XEvent[] events = this.XEvents.Where(e => e.Id > 150000).ToArray();
```

SQL Profiler shows that when I touch XEvents property in first time, Linq-to-SQL loads ALL 163000 of rows, and then executes LINQ methods on client side. Is it possible to force execution of Where to database side and do not load millions of rows I do not need?

Comment: What (and where) exactly is `this.XEvents` and where do you call this statement?

Comment: @GertArnold, XCore is LINQ-to-SQL generated class declared with 'partial' keyword and extended with custom methods. For instance, `XCore.GetRecentEvents()` method contains code in question. `this` is XCore object.